# Bash comprehensive list of IP addresses for a domain

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I'm trying to produce a list of all the possible ip addresses for a given domain name.  I think I'm close but don't know what I'm missing (or if there is a better way).

First I create a list of variations of the domain like so:

```
 webkinz.com
 www.webkinz.com
```

I then loop over this list and run dig on each variation like so:

```
 while read domain; do
    IPs=`dig $domain | grep $domain | grep -v ';' | awk '{ print $5 }'`;
    echo " ${IPs}" >> /tmp/IPs; #array
 done < /tmp/mylist

 sort -u /tmp/IPs > /tmp/TheIPs; #remove duplicates
 cat /tmp/TheIPs| tr -d "\n" > /tmp/IPs  #remove new lines (making it 1 long line)
```

My IPs file looks like this:

```
  66.48.69.100 www.webkinz.com.edgesuite.net.a1339.g.akamai.net.
```

Only 3 problems. :-(

1. Dig returned domains when I was only expecting ip addresses.
2. Some how my script deleted the spaces between the domains.
3. Some of the ip addresses from `dig www.webkinz.com` are missing.

So, how should I do this?  Do I somehow figure out if dig returned another domain instead of an ip address and run dig on that domain?  Do I just ignore domain names returned from dig and figure the ip addresses is sufficient?  I want to catch every ip address that will resolve to the domain if possible.  I didn't think it should be this hard.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you want to overwrite the contents of your hard-earned file of IP addresses? `sort -u /tmp/mylist > /tmp/IPs`

Comment: Are you sure your script is ok? In the line `sort -u /tmp/mylist > /tmp/IPs; #remove duplicates` you're overwriting the `/tmp/IPs` file content

Comment: Thanks for noting the errors in my post.  I have corrected it.  It wasn't an error in my real script. I just made a mistake when renaming my lists for this posting.

Comment: yes I think you have to recurs, but note the dns may not tell you all of the IPs. I think some services (e.g. google) report different IP addresses in different territories and times.

Comment: That's fine.  It is sufficient to know the ones for this time and location.  This script will be run often (like every 10 minutes) to make sure the list is up-dated.

Comment: `cat INPUT | tr ... > OUTPUT` has unnecessary usage of `cat`: why not just `tr ... < INPUT > OUTPUT`? :-)

Comment: You can get rid of the temporaries altogether: `while ...; do ...; echo " ${IPs}"; done < /tmp/mylist | sort -u | tr -d "\n"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get just the IP addresses, use `dig +short`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r domain
do
    dig +short "$domain"
done < /tmp/mylist | sort -u | awk '{printf "%s ", $0} END {printf "\n"}' > outputfile
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(xargs -a /tmp/mylist dig +short | sort -u) > outputfile
```

Using echo with an unquoted argument drops the newlines except at the end.

You don't need any intermediate variables or temporary files.

Comment: This works great!  Thanks!  My version of xargs doesn't support a -a option so I went with the first approach.  Now only one of my original 3 problems persists; the output still has domains in it.  So, do I need to loop over my output and do a dig on any domains I find?

Comment: @user548971: Try `dig +short "$domain" | grep -v '[[:alpha:]]'` to eliminate domains or `dig +short "$domain" | while read -r result ; do if [[ $result =~ [[:alpha:]] ]]; then dig +short "$result"; else echo "$result"; fi; done` to recurse.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following modification in your script to resolve the dns names when is not an ip address

```
while read domain; do
    IPs=`dig $domain | grep $domain | grep -v ';' | awk '{ print $5 }'`;

    # detect if '$IPs' is an ip address 
    grep "\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}" <(echo $IPs) >/dev/null 2>&1

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
        # if IPs is an ip address add it to the file   
        echo " ${IPs}" >> /tmp/IPs; #array          
    else 
        # if not, resolve the domain name using the 'host' command (take just the first line using 'head -1') 
        host $IPs | grep "has address" | head -1 | awk '{ print $4 }' >> /tmp/IPs
    fi

done < mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

`dig` gives different types of responses, so it's possible that the fifth column contains domain names. The fifth column will be IP addresses only when the response line is an `A` response. I would suggest:

```
dig -t A $domain
```

instead of

```
dig $domain
```

to restrict the type.

Comment: ah, good catch.  But would that result in ip addresses that will potentially resolve to the domain but not be in my list?

Comment: @user548971: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What would cause the omission?

Comment: ...only looking at the A response and ignoring the domains.  Could it not be that one of the domains returned in the dig command has an ip address that will resolve to the same location as the primary domain?  If not then maybe I don't understand dig.

Answer (score 0):

I know this already answered; however, for a list of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, try this:

Script:

```
info=$(host google.com); echo "$info" | grep "has address" | awk '{print $4}'; echo "$info" | grep "IPv6" | awk '{print $5}'

host - get the IP addresses
grep - filter the addresses
awk - print the correct strings
```

script (less lines):

```
host google.com | awk '/address/ {print $NF}'
```

Output:

```
74.125.45.102
74.125.45.113
74.125.45.138
74.125.45.139
74.125.45.100
74.125.45.101
2607:f8b0:4002:c01::8a
```